# Cancel BackgroundWorker ( Single Method without Loop)

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, backgroundworker

How do I cancel the below job?

```
workerLoad = new BackgroundWorker();
                    workerLoad.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;


                    workerLoad.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
                    {
                        //Thread.Sleep(100);
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => BindWorkarea(selectedFolder,false)));
                        //Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => workareaListView.DataContext = pages));                       
                    };
                    workerLoad.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
                    {
                        Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
                    };
                    workerLoad.RunWorkerAsync();
```

I don't have loop running to check cancellation status and set cancelAsync

```
 if (workerLoad.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        break;
    }
```

DoWork, Has got only one method which is looping through the files and adding to the screen using dispatcher.

Comment: You are not making use of `BackgroundWorker`. You do all the job in `Dispatcher` only. There is no need of `BackgroundWorker` at all.

Comment: You are right, I need to update UI for every file I found, so I'm running everything under dispatcher. How do I cancel the dispatcher?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing all the work in one function...

You would need to break your work into a loop and put the loop inside the `BackgroundWorker` then inside of the loop update the UI via `Dispather`. This way you will get a chance to break up the process at will.

Comment: I believe there is a way to cancel dispatcher beginInvoke. I will have to find this out, This concepts are bit new to me (.Net4.0/4.5). I Will update here later